Cartoon show of the 2000's with episode about fashion?
There is a cartoon show that I watched somewhere in the late 2000's. I can't remember what the show was about, but I remember one specific episode. 
In the episode a girl (I think one of the main characters of the show) wanted to have new, cool clothes for a party. Suddenly there's a "magic mirror" that gives her clothes every day. She becomes more popular, but later on the mirror begins to take over her life and demands her to wear the clothes it gives. The girl has brown hair and it's mostly in a ponytail. The show was in 2D. And it wasn't an anime show.
It's not much information, but I hope someone can help me out.
